# Unable to send list of data from controller to jsp

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, maven, jsp

I already fetched list of data from database to controller, unable to send this data into jsp, it's showing only return string.

here is my view part

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#searchleader').submit(
    function(event) {
        var all={village:$('#village').val(),taluka:$('#taluka').val(),district:$('#district').val(),state:$('#stateDrop').val()};
        var data = all;
        $.ajax({
            url : $("#searchleader").attr("action"),
            data : data,
            type : "GET",

            success : function(response) {
                alert( response );
            },
            error : function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
<form action="searchresult" id="searchleader" method="POST">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                        <select id="stateDrop"
                            title="State &lt;i class=&quot;fa fa-angle-down&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;">
                            <option value="small">State</option>
                            <c:forEach items="${stateList}" var="state">
                                <option value="${state.state_Id}">${state.state_Name}</option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                        <select id="district">
                            <option value="small">District</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
                        <select id="taluka">
                            <option value="small">Taluka</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
                        <select id="village"
                            title="Villages &lt;i class=&quot;fa fa-angle-down&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;">
                            <option value="small">Villages</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

This is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchresult",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String searchLeaderList(
        @RequestParam (value="state",required=false) Integer state_id,
        @RequestParam (value="district",required=false) Integer ds_id,
        @RequestParam (value="taluka",required=false) Integer t_id,
        @RequestParam(value="village",required=false)Integer v_id,ModelMap model){
    List<LeaderName> leadernames=leaderNameService.findLeaders(state_id, ds_id, t_id, v_id);
    model.addAttribute("lname",leadernames);
    return "home/list-of-polititian";   
}
```

The problem is after fetched all the data needs to send another jsp page along with list of data but it's not going to that page. after getting success response showing only "home/list-of-polititian". I konw this is string which is why it's not going to another page.Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `@ResponseBody` from your controller method. When using `@ResponseBody` response will not be redirected to views, instead it will response with json value.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchresult",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String searchLeaderList(
        @RequestParam (value="state",required=false) Integer state_id,
        @RequestParam (value="district",required=false) Integer ds_id,
        @RequestParam (value="taluka",required=false) Integer t_id,
        @RequestParam(value="village",required=false)Integer v_id,ModelMap model){
    List<LeaderName> leadernames=leaderNameService.findLeaders(state_id, ds_id, t_id, v_id);
    model.addAttribute("lname",leadernames);
    return "home/list-of-polititian";   
}
```